# Вопрос по DNS запросам

Tags: windows, dns, windows-server-2012

Есть AD в 3-мя контроллерами, два находятся в дата-центре,один стоит в офисе. Первый в настройках это основной контроллер dc-02,второй - это локальный контроллер. Когда падает туннель между офис и дата-центром, происходит такая фигня. Основной ДНС не доступен и система не разрезолвывает доменные имена,не обращается с этим же запросом к локальному контроллеру.Помагает только ipconfig /flushdns. Вопрос,как можно это пофиксить? Думаю об уменьшении времени жизни записей в ДНС,может у кого-то еще есть решения какие-то. Все на винде